# Is there a way to prefix the url of an image referenced in .scss in case of CDN usage?

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

Currently in my `.scss` file I have

```
.grid_pic {
    width : $width-grid;
    background : transparent url('/img/exemple_bg.png') 0 0 repeat;
}
```

**Is there a way of removing the `/img/` and to define a variable, OR a configuration files that tells to prefix all the images with the value I want ?**

So the day we decide to serve our images via CDN, we just have to change 1 config line from `/img/` to `http://cdn.example.com/` instead of changing all the Url of the images ?

How would you achieve that ? (a variable or is there already a config for that ?)

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the [interpolation](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#interpolation_) syntax along with a variable:

```
background: url(#{$path_variable_name}/site/background.jpg);
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try with image-url function ?

http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/helpers/urls/#image-url